# 301 redirect, change parameter in url, same domain and file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have duplicate problem so I need to do some redirects,
I understand as there are parameters I need to use Query_String, however as I don't want to change page, only the parameters, I have no idea

I need to change a url like this:

```
    /svenska/utflykter/tur-from.php?trop=trop&ciudad=Marbella&tour=Sevilla
```

to

```
    /svenska/utflykter/tur-from.php?ciudad=Marbella&tour=Sevilla
```

As you can see I only want to take away trop=trop however not on all pages, only on the page in question.

Any idea, I have searched, thanks

Comment: If this is all about SEO - couldn't you just specify the canonical URL and not worry too much about duplicate content? Just seems a bit like overkill to me is all...

Comment: well, pages been dropped due to this on my main keyword, and I believe a 301 is quicker, as it is a bug, pages is the same and that parameter should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ciudad=([^&]+).*&tour=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?svenska/utflykter/tur-from\.php$ /svenska/utflykter/tur-from.php?ciudad=%1&tour=%2 [R=301,QSD]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks, This did not work properly, gave me same value for tour as for ciudad. Ciudad has the correct value.

Comment: I think the second should be 2%, looks like work with 2%
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ciudad=([^&]+).*&tour=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?svenska/utflykter/tur-from\.php$ /svenska/utflykter/tur-from.php?ciudad=%1&tour=%2 [R=301,QSD]
Thanks

Comment: Of course, that was a lack of attention on my side. Sorry for that.